# Hazelcast Session Replciation With Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, session, hazelcast, session-replication

Am following this documentation for Hazelcast based session replication in a Spring Boot APP.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/hazelcast-spring.html

The code works fine when a local Hazelcast node gets created from spring boot however what i need is a Hazelcast client code to connect to standalone cluster and do the replication and return back the Session ID as a  header in "x-auth-header " field.

Client code is something like this

```
   ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
    clientConfig.getGroupConfig().setName("dev").setPassword("dev-pass");
    clientConfig.getNetworkConfig().addAddress("x.x.x.x");
```

I am able to get it working with a WEB Filter but it stores the value as cookie and what i need is the header strategy to work.

I couldn't find any documenation or help to acheive it using a Hazelcast client. Can some one please guide me on how to do it.

Thanks
Aravind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have

```
@Bean
public HeaderHttpSessionStrategy sessionStrategy() {
  return new HeaderHttpSessionStrategy();
}
```

If everything else is working, this should be all you need

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the quick reply . It works when I create a springawarewebfilter and then define the cookie params.
In that case when I add the header strategy it doesn't work and still resolves to cookies.

May be it was misleading but it worked with springawarewebfilter which I think is different as the above specified link creates a different filter for handling session

Answer (score 0):

The issue was related to the server nodes and firewall in between. Migrated to a separate set of nodes and everything started working.